# Como definir propriedades de um JSON para utilizar em um for loop?

Tags: python, json, loop, flask

Estou lendo um JSON parecido com este: [Google Books](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=harry%20potter) e tentando exibi-lo no HTML. O input de pesquisa do usuário é o `seek` que é recebido através do `request.form.get` abaixo:

```py
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, session

@app.route('/search', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def search():
    """Pesquisa um livro utilizando a API do Google Books"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            seek = request.form.get("seek")
            url = f'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q={seek}'
            response = requests.get(url)
            response.raise_for_status()
        except requests.RequestException:
            return None
        # Parse response
        try:
            search = response.json()
            search = {
                "totalItems": int(search["totalItems"]),
                "items": search["items"]
            }
            return render_template("search.html", search=search)
        except (KeyError, TypeError, ValueError):
            return None
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")
```

A pesquisa funciona bem, mas ainda não sei onde estou errando na hora de enviar para o HTML. Estou tentando exibir da seguinte forma:

```html
{% for seek in search %}
  <figure>
    <a><img src="{{ seek['items']['imageLinks']['thumbnail'] }}"></a>
    <p>{{ seek["items"]["volumeInfo"]["title"] }}</p>
    <p>{{ seek["items"]["volumeInfo"]["authors"] }}</p>
  </figure>
{% endfor %}
```

O terminal me retorna a seguinte mensagem:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'items'
```

Alguém saberia me indicar o que estou deixando passar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, pelo que vejo, a estrutura de search seria algo assim:

```js
{
  "kind": "books#volumes",
  "totalItems": 894,
  "items": [{...}, {...}]
}
```

quando você roda o seu `for` sobre o objeto `search`, a váriavel `seek` assumirá como valor as propriedade do objeto (`"kind"`, `"totalItems"`, `"items"`)

Sendo assim,você não esta iterando sobre os itens como você gostaria

o correto seria

```html
{% for seek in search["items"] %}
  <figure>
    <a><img src="{{ search["items"][seek]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['thumbnail'] }}"></a>
    <p>{{ search["items"][seek]["volumeInfo"]["title"] }}</p>
    <p>{{ search["items"][seek]["volumeInfo"]["authors"].join(",") }}</p>
  </figure>
{% endfor %}
```

Observe que `authors` também é um array, por isso recomendo o `join` ou outra forma de exibir

Observe também `imageLinks` esta dentro de `volumeInfo`

Outro ponto de melhoria, é que em javascript, um mapa é tratado como objeto, então você não precisa acessar as propriedades como esta fazendo, mas assim:

aqui estou adcionando também uma checagem para evitar undefined

```html
{% for seek in search.items %}
  <figure>
    <a><img src="{{ search.items[seek].volumeInfo.imageLinks && search.items[seek].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail }}"></a>
    <p>{{ search.items[seek].volumeInfo.title }}</p>
    <p>{{ search.items[seek].volumeInfo.imageLinks && search.items[seek].volumeInfo.authors.join(",") }}</p>
  </figure>
{% endfor %}
```

PS:
seek nesta sintax carrega o indice do array

PS2:
você precisa decidir o que fazer quando o attributo não existe

Comment: Muita boa sua solução Fernando! Porém, algumas das pesquisas estão retornando `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'imageLinks'`. Pelos termos que andei pesquisando, verifiquei que alguns livros não possuem thumbnail, sabe me dizer qual seria a saída nesse caso?

Comment: Corrigi ... seek nesta sintax carrega o indice do array